# Nginx и proxy_pass с другого сервера

Tags: nginx, proxy, static

Есть локальный сайт, *mycompany.ru* и есть внешний ресурс, *domain.ru*

Необходимо, чтобы по адресу *mycompany.ru/folder/* подгружался сайт *domain.ru/*

Сделал:

```
location /folder/ {
  proxy_pass http://domain.ru/
}
```

В результате контент подгружается, но статика валится с 404 ошибкой, т.к. на сайте источнике прописана относительно корня.

В итоге получаем:

```
http://mycompany.ru/js/jquery.js - 404
http://mycompany.ru/css/style.css - 404
```

и т.д.

Прошу подсказать, в какую сторону копать.. Гуглил, читал маны, но видимо что-то не понимаю...

Comment: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html

Comment: `http://mycompany.ru/js/jquery.js` должно тоже с `domain.ru` браться или нет?

Comment: За ngx_http_sub_module спасибо, видел этот модуль, но пересобирать nginx очень не хочется :(

Comment: @МАН69К вся статика доступна на domain.ru

Comment: @PumPurum: тогда почему вы перенаправляете туда лишь запросы на `/folder/`?

Comment: @МАН69К намёк понял :) Вы предлагаете сделать еще один локейшн на статику в каталоге /folder/ и так же забирать её с domain.ru, верно? Разве в данном случае решится проблема с  путями от корня? прошу прощения, если туплю, но пока не представляю картину

Comment: Этот вопрос задают примерно раз в неделю. На него нет одного общего правильного ответа. Если вы контролируете `domain.ru`, то исправьте там пути к ресурсам. Если нет, то вам уже подсказали вариант с `sub`. Ещё один вариант использовать отдельный домен `sub.mycompany.ru`